What IAM permission is required to use Vertex AI's CachedContent resource?
I'm trying to restrict permission to only have access to use the context cache.
When I look at the API/code documentation I see perms for some calls like this:

That tells me UpdateCacheConfig calls requires the aiplatform.cacheConfigs.update permission.
But annoyingly everything under GenAiCacheService says nothing about what IAM perms are required to make the API requests:

What permissions are relevant here for GenAiCacheService access?
Edit
Have not confirmed it works yet, but I was able to create a custom role with the following, undocumented perms and bind to project: ["aiplatform.cachedContents.create", "aiplatform.cachedContents.update", "aiplatform.cachedContents.delete"]
If it works I'll update as answer.

Perhaps because it's a v1beta1 service? A good candidate for feedback on Google's documentation site. Have you tried invoking the method with a Service Account without any roles to see what the platform throws back at you? It may tell you what it's expecting. The usual candidates Vertex AI IAM roles and all up IAM don't contain any obvious candidates.

OK, so I tried it (admittedly unfamiliar with Vertex AI) and I received the (in hindsight) not unexpected "aiplatform.cachedContents.list denied ...". And, disappointingly, this permission isn't listed in the project's Roles browser either. So I'm outta ideas.

The minimal service-specific role that I've found that works is roles/aiplatform.viewer.

Did roles/aiplatform.viewer give you access to write to the cache? I was hoping to get a definitive response here from a gcp person here. I was surprised to not see any mention aiplatform.cachedContents.* perms and from what you've found maybe they are there, but undocumented. I wonder if there are aiplatform.cachedContents.update | delete | create permissions that can be assigned via a custom role I can create.

I only tried the list method. So viewer may be suitable for it but you may need user (perhaps admin) for any create. I was unable to surface the roles/permissions anywhere so it's unclear whether the roles exist or whether they're effected by some side-effect of the other roles. I think you couldn't assign these permissions to a custom role. If you pay for Cloud Support, that'd be the best route.

You could try Google's issue tracker but my recent experience is that Google's getting better at pushing back on customer feedback (!) so, developer beware (former Googler here and understand your frustration). I searched and found no results

Well despite it being undocumented these perms are valid and I was able to create a custom role.
Working terraform code for illustrative purposes:
resource "google_organization_iam_custom_role" "vertex_cache_access" {
  org_id      = "xxx"
  role_id     = "myrole"
  title       = "My Role"
  description = "Context cache access. See: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/context-cache/context-cache-overview"
  permissions = ["aiplatform.cachedContents.create", "aiplatform.cachedContents.update", "aiplatform.cachedContents.delete"]
}

I created this role, applied it to a project binding and confirmed it allowed a gsa to CRUD the cache.
